# Facebook Login with Firebase and LoginButton For IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to perform a `FacebookLogin` using `Firebase` and the `Facebook Login button`, but I keep getting this

> error:Facebook login was cancelled.
>
> 2016-04-01 19:08:15.721
>   biblos[778:408049] Warning: Attempt to present
>    on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

User logged out...

Facebook login was cancelled.

> 2016-04-01 19:08:53.675 biblos[778:408049] Warning: Attempt to present
>    on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

My `ViewController` code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




// MARK: - Facebook Login

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
{
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://biblos-thebookapp.firebaseio.com")
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: {
        (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

            ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken,
                withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                    }
            })
        }
    })

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
{
    print("User logged out...")
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is deprecated. Try to use `logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:` instead and pass your UIViewController or nil (topmost will be used).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

Comment: I'm not sure wha to put in the fromViewController part. I put nil and had the same problem

Comment: this viewController will get an updated event, e.g. viewWillAppear() after Facebook status will be updated. I don't like it, it gives me less control, but another method is deprecated.

Comment: Ahh ok. I am also still having trouble with the handler also. I don't know what to put there.